# Backwards VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, vlookup

I currently have a big table of data in excel that I need connected to a separate excel file. In column N I have the date and I want to use this date as the value that allows me to connect the two files. In column A I have a Serial Number. I want to do a Backwards VLOOKUP that looks in column N and provides me with the value in Column A. I currently have this code:

```
=VLOOKUP($G$2,CHOOSE({2,1},'FILENAMESHEET1'!$A$2:$A$1048576,'FILENAMESHEET1'!$N$2:$N$687),2,0)
```

This provides me the first serial number that appears with this specific date. How can I get the 2nd,3rd, Nth serial number that appears on a specific date.

Comment: Look in to `Index/Match`. Vlookup doesn't go right to left.

Comment: Is this two questions?  How to do a backwards vlookup and how to get the 1st, 2nd, 3rd... match?

Comment: Yes @JNevill sorry for being unclear

Comment: Have you looked on here for similar questions / answers - especially for 2nd 3rd matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=INDEX('FILENAMESHEET1'!$A:$A,MATCH($G$2,'FILENAMESHEET1'!$N:$N,0)
```

This will bring in the first found.

---

To answer your second, one must get a little more creative.

This will bring the first,second, third...

Put this in the first cell and copy/drag down

```
=INDEX('FILENAMESHEET1'!$A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW('FILENAMESHEET1'!$N$2:INDEX('FILENAMESHEET1'!$N:$N,MATCH(1E+99,'FILENAMESHEET1'!$N:$N)))/('FILENAMESHEET1'!$N$2:INDEX('FILENAMESHEET1'!$N:$N,MATCH(1E+99,'FILENAMESHEET1'!$N:$N))= $G$2),ROW(1:1)))
```

If your data in Column N is text instead of numbers then you will need to change both `1E+99` to `"zzz"`.

As it is copied/dragged down it will return the next match and the next ...

Comment: Absolute life saver. I had almost given up, you are a god my friend